# Issue with confirmation window

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a HW project and I've followed it step by step to try and get this confirmation window to pop up but can't figure it out.  I'm not getting any console errors so I assume my code is just broken somewhere.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <article>
        <h2>Change of address form</h2>
        <form>
            <fieldset id="contactinfo">
                <label for="addrinput">
            Street Address
          </label>
                <input type="text" id="addrinput" name="Address" />
                <label for="cityinput">
            City
          </label>
                <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="City" />
                <label for="stateinput">
            State/Province
          </label>
                <input type="text" id="stateinput" name="State" />
                <label for="zipinput">
            Zip/Postal Code
          </label>
                <input type="number" id="zipinput" name="Zip" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="submitsection">
                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </article>
    <script>
        function processInput() {
            var propertyWidth = 300;
            var propertyHeight = 100;
            var winLeft = ((screen.width - propertyWidth) / 2);
            var winTop = ((screen.height - propertyHeight) / 2);
            var winOptions = "width=300,height=100";
            winOptions += ",left=" + winLeft;
            winOptions += ",top=" + winTop;
            window.open("confirm.htm", "confirm", winOptions);
        }

        function createEventListener() {
            var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
            if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
                submitButton.addEventListener("click", processInput,
                    false);
            } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
                submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", processInput);
            }
        }

        if (window.addEventListner) {
            window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You define two functions, but you don't execute them anywhere. You have a bunch of code that never gets executed.

Comment: I thought that was the point of the eventlisteners, to execute onclick of the submit button.

Comment: They would, if they weren't wrapped in a function that never gets called.

Comment: add the function to your button
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onlick="functionThatYouWantToExecute()"/>

Comment: Yeah, Im not supposed to edit the existing HTML, just add my JS.  I see that I was short a curly brace after my second function.  Thank you all.

Comment: @DanielMiller oh, that explains the odd indentation. Yeah, you should try and use an auto-formatter when possible so that it normalizes your indentation and emphasizes whether a block of code is inside a function or not. I edited to fix your indentation, I guess that was the cause of the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, I am still very new to coding, I appreciate your input!  Any suggestions on a auto-formatter?

Comment: @DanielMiller if your IDE doesn't have an auto-format feature, you can always use this for JavaScript and HTML: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: I'm just using Notepad++, not sure if it does or not! But I will use that in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I thought this had fixed it before but I realized I had added the processInput function to my button to ensure the code worked. After moving this outside the createEventListener function and removing the processInput function from onClick of my Submit button the code still isn't executing.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could be a number of issues; your browser blocks the popup (which, you really shouldn't be doing in the first place, but I understand it's a HW assignment). If that's not the problem, then the popup loads, but the button submits the form anyway which causes the page to refresh, thus defeating the purpose of your confirmation window. Other than those symptoms, I can't really think of what else would go wrong in this particular scenario. Perhaps you should elaborate more than "the code still isn't executing".

Comment: I updated the snippet to my current code, everything works perfectly fine if I attach the function to the submit button but it seems like my eventhandlers aren't executing still.

Answer (score 1):

Move this code outside of `createEventListener`:

```
if (window.addEventListner) {
    window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
}
```

Comment: I thought this had fixed it before but I realized I had added the processInput function to my button to ensure the code worked.  After moving this outside the createEventListener function and removing the processInput function from onClick of my Submit button the code still isn't executing.

Comment: @DanielMiller, move your `<script>` block to `<head>` or simply call `createEventListener` directly where you have it.